# Eucalyptus web-ui - get accountid in eucalyptus-web.properties

Tags: eucalyptus, webui

i have a question about the web ui interface of eucalyptus in the context of my bachelor thesis.
i reference in the eucalyptus-web.properties to a static url. (like 123456/index.html) now i want to replace the "123456" with  the accountid of the user wich is logged in. is there any solution of this problem?

i would be very grateful for any answer.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

`eucalyptus-web.properties` file is just a set of properties that are available to the Web UI code. They can be changed (by a cloud admin) to customize some of the text in the UI of the particular installation without recompiling the source.

If you are asking whether the system defines some variables, like "name of the current user" that can be used in the custom strings, the short answer is: **no**. There is no support for any variable substitution in those strings at the moment.

However, if you are changing the Web UI code and introducing new properties, it wouldn't be hard to devise a syntax for variables and perform variable substitution over text of properties.